# What's wrong with my these two Bash pipeline methods for counting average file size in a directory?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, pipeline

The problem: I am trying to calculate an average file size for the directory I'm in (ignoring sub-directories) using one-liners. I have two methods:

```
ls -l | gawk '{sum += $5; n++;} END {print sum/n;}'
```

and

```
var1=$(du -Ss| awk '{print $1}') ; var2=$(ls -l | wc -l) ; echo $var1/$var2 | bc
```

They seem to yield similar numbers, albeit different units (first one in kB, second one in MB).

The numbers themselves however are slightly wrong. What's going on? Which one is more right?

Comment: have a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/94217/ls-and-du-shows-very-different-size). P.s. Is ls aliased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` and `ls` report differently.  Consider this part of the `du` man page:

```
   --apparent-size
          print apparent sizes,  rather  than  disk  usage;  although  the
          apparent  size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes
          in ('sparse') files, internal  fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,
          and the like
```

That gives an idea about the possible differences between what `ls` shows (apparent size) and what `du` shows (by default, the actual disk usage).

```
$ truncate -s 10737418240 sparse
$ ls -l sparse
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 10737418240 Feb 20 00:19 sparse
$ du sparse
0       sparse
$ ls -ls sparse
0 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 10737418240 Feb 20 00:19 sparse
```

The above shows the difference in reporting for a sparse file.

Also, the counting of files using `ls -l` will include subdirectories, symlinks, etc.  You can instead use `find` to show only files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Comment: "`du` will be more accurate"?  In what way is `ls` less accurate?  It's just a matter of understanding what is being reported, not an issue of accuracy.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll amend my answer.